# return url for arcgisoutput

Tags: arcgis-server

I have a server setup that has port 8080 assigned to ArcGIS Server installation and port 80 to our custom WebADF application.

From one of our application, we make a call that generates an image in the output directory. The issue that I have is that the return url doesnt contain 8080 in the url string. It returns this string: http://sfs012/arcgisoutput/_ags_mapa...8cb868696e.jpg

I am expecting to get: http://sfs012:8080/arcgisoutput/_ags...8cb868696e.jpg

I have tried lot of things but can't seem to figure out how and where to make thing change. Looking for some feedback.

Thanks
 Jay

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is change the ArcGIS Server's Ouput URL, if you're using ArcCatalog to manage your ArcGIS Server, right click on the server and go to "Server Properties", there you should have a tab which will let you set the output directories and URL's.

Please keep in mind that you will not be able to change these output directories, as long as any of your services are running, so stop all of your services and try.